# How to share Scenes between users - not all devices are visible

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

My test action adds a number of devices including lights, fans and scenes which I'd like to make available to all users in the Structure/Home. However, the type of device seems to change how/when it is shared and I can't find any documentation on this.

My first attempt was by linking only one user:

- **Lights:** shared
- **Fans:** shared
- **Scenes:** not shared

I then linked the second user to my action, and found inconsistent behaviour:

- **Lights:** shared
- **Fans:** duplicated
- **Scenes:** "shared" (presumably as each user has their own copy now)

Why are different device types treated differently by HomeGraph?

And where is this documented? Neither the [HomeGraph concepts](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/homegraph) page nor the [Scene trait reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/scene) page mention this.

In fact, I'm struggling to find any guidance on how to handle multiple users linking to my action from the same household. I get the impression (from the bug tracker/stackoverflow) that we *should not* be thinking about individual users, so why are Scenes scoped to a user that I can't identify!

Comment: Have you checked your [Action logs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging#smart_home_events) to verify your SYNC response behaves as intended between users? Additionally, are you seeing any other errors when the second user account is attempting to control/update devices?